# SqlAlchemy + SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am attempting to connect to `Microsoft SQL Server` on a remote machine like this:

```
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(pyodbc.drivers())
    constr = "mssql+pyodbc://xxx:xxxxxxxx@xxx.xx.xx.xx:1433/Underlying?driver={'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'}"
    print(constr)
    engine = create_engine(constr)
```

The `print(pyodbc.drivers())` outputs:

```
['ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server']
```

However, I get this exception:

> pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '{'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'};Server=xxx.xx.xxx.xx,1433;Database=Underlying;UID=xxx;PWD=xxxx' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Comment: The ODBC driver name should not be enclosed in single quotes. The curly brackets are also unnecessary. And strictly speaking the driver name should be URL escaped. `?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server` should work.

Comment: That seems to get passed that problem. Now I have a new one will open up another question.

Comment: One thing, I used the '&'. The ? doesn't work.

Comment: "mssql+pyodbc://uname:pwd@xxx.xx.xx.xx:1433/Underlying?Trusted_Connection=yes&driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"